# having trouble loading a record in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i am having trouble loading a record using find by Id from the view. i can load it from the commandline with the rails console but i cant seem to load it in the browser view.

***my controller file:***

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

***model file***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

***view file***

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

***routes file***

```
Twitster::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  match "/about", to: 'home#about'

  match "/contact", to: 'home#contact'

  match "/help", to: 'home#help'

  root :to => 'home#index'

end
```

This is the error I get in the browser:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#show
>
> undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
>
> Rails.root: /home/hilarl/workspace/twitster Application Trace |
>   Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"1"}
>
> Show session dump
>
> Show env dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> None

and here is the code from the 'full trace':

```
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__27655154__call__142737833__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/hilarl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Any help please?

---

i had an error in my main layout file where i had some partials and i had the path to the partials wrong which was causing the error.

Comment: currently i just have the code "<%= @user.name %>" in the show.html.erb since i am only trying to output the data before starting to lay them out

Comment: try raise @user.inspect in show method of controller after  
user = User.find(params[:id]) line because I have doubt that user is nil.

Comment: hey have you not making loop in your view.html file?

Comment: i'm only trying to display the selected user's name like 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/1' so since its defined in the controller to find the entry by id i am expecting the name of the user with the id 1 to show up when i type that url so no need for a loop

Comment: have you try to inspect the value of  @user what is the result of that?

Comment: 1.9.3p194 :001 > User.find(1)
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Hilal Agil", email: "hilaal@me.com", created_at: "2012-05-28 06:44:28", updated_at: "2012-05-28 06:44:28", passwor
d_digest: "$2a$10$aSysU94ojZ6LBEgENa/YH.a4kiMrZ5Spem3h.RTn1Qk3...">

Comment: i get the result when i try to find it with the id in the rails console

Comment: have you using any gem like devise for this? and please run rake routes and post result of that.

Comment: no i havent used 'devise'. the rake routes result:

Comment: users GET /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
    about        /about(.:format)          home#about
  contact        /contact(.:format)        home#contact
     help        /help(.:format)           home#help
     root        /                         home#index

Comment: hey try to restart the server and  implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it, I think you had to do is restart the rails server.